# crc32 in php and as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I am planning to use crc32 checksum to check data integrity on REST API calls. I use a crc32 library from 
http://www.icana.org.ar/ICANACardRotator/source/nochump/util/zip/CRC32.as

This and php crc32 function are giving different outputs.
In as3 I use the below code

```
var c:crc32 = new crc32();
var arr:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
arr.writeObject("Hello World!");
c.update(arr);
trace(c.getValue());
```

which gives me 2098676879

in php I use

```
<?php
$str = crc32("Hello World!");
printf("%u\n",$str);
?>
```

which outputs 472456355

Can somebody help me telling what is the difference?

Comment: Have you checked the byte arrays? Most probably those are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ByteArray.writeObject` writes `AMF` encoded object into `ByteArray` instead of utf string, that's why you got different result. So the solution is to use `writeUTFBytes`:

```
        var c:CRC32 = new CRC32();
        var arr:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        arr.writeUTFBytes("Hello World!");
        c.update(arr);
        trace(c.getValue()); //output 472456355
```